# How sum totals of variable generated from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

If I am parsing an xml file with something like :

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "file.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success:   function  parseXml(data)
    {
      $(data).find("ITEM").each(function()
        {
            var quant=$("QTY", this).text();
        };
     };
});
```

How would I sum the total of everything that is returned in QTY?

Comment: boo, you should learn to accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get it, add it. Optimized for efficiency using context.

```
$.get(
    "xml.xml",
    {},
    function( data )
    {
        var total = 0;

        $( "ITEM > QTY", data ).each(
            function()
            {
                var num = parseInt( $(this).text() );

                if( !isNaN(num) )
                    total += num;
            }
        );
    },
    "xml"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

be aware of js rounding problems when adding up floats in js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "file.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
       var total = 0;
       $(data).find("ITEM").each(function() {
          var quant = parseFloat($("QTY", this).text());
          // you might run into rounding problems when adding
          // floats in js, workaround gets right results 
          total = ( ( total * 100 )+( quant * 100 ) ) / 100;
       });
    };
});
```

Comment: added it, sorry, plz accept if it solved your prob, thx -> see CrazyDart above

Answer (score 0):

```
success:   function parseXml(data){
                var sum = 0;
                $(data).find("ITEM").each(function() {
                    var quant=$("QTY", this).text();
                    sum += parseFloat(quant); //or parseInt() if you're sure you'll only have or only care about integral values
                };
                //at this point sum holds the sum of all QTY values
                console.log("The sum is ", sum);
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "file.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success:   function  parseXml(data)
    {
      var total = 0;
      $(data).find("ITEM").each(function()
        {
            var quant=$("QTY", this).text();
            if(quant != null && quant != "")
                total += parseInt(quant);
        };
     };
});
```